# Was Bourdieu's 'Ökonomisches Kapital, kulturelles Kapital, soziales Kapital' written originally in German?

Tags: sociology

Self explaining question. I did an extensive online research to find the original text, but it doesn't go before

In: Reinhard Kreckel (Hg.), »Soziale Ungleichheiten« (Soziale Welt Sonderband 2), Göttingen 1983, S. 183-198
Originalbeitrag, übersetzt von Reinhard Kreckel.

It should mean there must also be a French version which I'm unable to find.

Comment: The reference says "Originalbeitrag" which translates to "original contribution" which in turn would mean that it has been written for the purpose of (originally) being published in that book, possibly as a translation from the beginning.

Comment: @Philip Klöcking Just to clarify; do you mean that this text is the original text and not a translation from one of Bourdieu's publication? From what I understand "Ökonomisches Kapital, kulturelles Kapital, soziales Kapital" was written by Bourdieu (in French) and then the German version was published. But where is the French version then?

Comment: Probably only existing as an unpublished manuscript I would guess.

Comment: No traces found (by using proper names and french words);  the vols. from the College de France courses of the early '80s remained inaccessible (vol2 TOC mentions Les espèces et les formes de capital)

Answer (score 1):

This one sounds like it would have at least provided the foundation:

Pierre Bourdieu, « Les trois états du capital culturel », Actes de la recherche en sciences sociales, vol. 30,‎ novembre 1979, p. 3-6(DOI 0.3406/arss.1979.2654)